# Confusing results between NaiveBayes and LogistcRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I went through this quick [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTaxdJ6VYWE) on using Scikit learn and had a question about NaiveBayes vs Logistc Regression

[Here](https://github.com/justmarkham/pydata-dc-2016-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial_with_output.ipynb) is the link to the transcript -

You should be able to copy/paste the code below and run it. Please let me know if you get different answers!

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn import metrics

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

vect = CountVectorizer()

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pydata-dc-2016-tutorial/master/sms.tsv'
sms = pd.read_table(url, header=None, names=['label', 'message'])
sms['label_num'] = sms.label.map({'ham': 0, 'spam': 1})
X = sms.message
y = sms.label_num

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=1)

vect.fit(X_train)
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)

## NaiveBayes
nb = MultinomialNB()
nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)

# LogisticRegression
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)

# testing data
simple_text = ["this is a spam message spam spam spam"]
simple_test_dtm = vect.transform(simple_text)

# ***NaiveBayes***     
nb.predict(simple_test_dtm)
# array([1]) says this is spam

nb.predict_proba(simple_test_dtm)[:, 1]
# array([0.98743019]) 

# ****Logistic Regression***    
logreg.predict(simple_test_dtm)
# array([0]) says this is NOT spam

logreg.predict_proba(simple_test_dtm)[:, 1]
# array([0.05628297])

nb_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, nb_pred_class)
# 0.9885139985642498

lg_pred_class = logreg.predict(X_test_dtm)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, lg_pred_class)
# 0.9877961234745154
```

Two questions:

1.) Why is NaiveBayes returning that it is `Spam` when LogisticRegression is saying that it is `Ham`?

Both classifiers return a high accuracy score, but give different answers? That is confusing me. Am I doing something wrong?

2.) What does the `.predict_probab` score mean? The way I **thought** I understood it was how accurate the classifiers response is. ie NB is saying it believes its answer (1) is 98% accurate, but that would mean LogReg is saying its answer (0) is 6% accurate.

Which doesn't make sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spam` is your second class (i.e., at index `1`) in `sms.label.map({'ham': 0, 'spam': 1})`. So the probability you printed is the probability of the message being `spam`, not the probability of the model's predicted class. `logreg` gives `0.05628297` probability for the message being `spam` which means it gave about `0.9437` probability to `ham`. Both of your models are highly accurate but that doesn't mean they will agree on every test example. Naive bayes got this one right but logistic regression got it wrong, there should be other examples where the reverse is true.

Comment: so I am understanding this right? logreg said its 5% likely to be `ham` but also could mean it's 95% likely to be `spam`?

Comment: what happens when their are multiple classes and you can't? I assume you just have to go with the answer it gave you and "weight" it with its predict_proba?

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer which I have fixed. logreg said it's `spam` with 5% probability so it assigned 95% probability to ham.

Comment: yup! but what happens when there are more than 2 classes?

Comment: You would then perform one vs rest classification. Have a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier

Comment: you are most welcome. You can also look at `multi_class = 'multinomial' ` in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html. It gives you a probability over all classes using a single model.